# How to enable "View Source" in Process Monitor?

Tags: windows, process, sysinternals, process-monitor, procmon

[Sysinternals Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) has a button to "view the source" on a Event Properties > Stack element:

[image]

It is disabled in my trace. What do I need to enable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What do I need to enable it?

You need the source code for the process you are monitoring.

Here is an explanation from the authors of Process Monitor:

> **Stack**
>
> The Stack page shows the thread stack of the thread when the event was
>   recorded. The stack can be useful for determining the reason an event
>   took place and the component responsible for the event.
>
> ...
>
> If you specify a path to source files in the Symbol Configuration
>   dialog, **the Stack dialog's Source button will enable for any frame for
>   which line number symbols information is available and the source file
>   is present** in the paths you include. Clicking on the Source button
>   opens a text viewer that highlights the source code line referenced.

Source [Process Monitor Help - documentation.pdf](https://documentation.help/Process-Monitor/documentation.pdf) (PDF)